# MySQL check title from form input for same value, if same ignore, if different update another table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an "edit" form that loads various text inputs with pre-populated data (which was entered previously through an “input” form). I have 2 important text inputs that are unique because the user can choose to enter a custom title or custom description (as opposed to using the default title and/or description).

First off, the Students have a StTitlePref which tells us if they prefer Common or Scientific titles (TkTitleSci, TkTitleCom). So, that is known up front. For discussion, let’s assume that Common is pre-selected (TkTitleCom).

**Logic**

In the event that the user had already created a TaskInstance in the “input” form with a ***default title***, when the “edit” form loads with the prepopulated data, it will load that ***default title***. When the user submits the form, I would like to do a database check to see if the title is exactly the same as the default. If it is the same, I don’t want to add the data into TaskInstance.TkInstCustomTitleCom (it should remain NULL) and basically the form data for this field will be ignored. I want the TaskInstance record to rely on the TaskInstance.fkTaskID to load the Tasks.TkTitleCom.

In the event that the user had already created a TaskInstance in the “input” form with a ***custom title***, when the “edit” form loads with the prepopulated data, it will load that ***custom title***. When the user submits the form, I would like to do a database check to see if the title is exactly the same as the default. Since it will not be the same, I want to add the data into TaskInstance.TkInstCustomTitleCom.

I would like to apply this same logic to TkDesc and TkInstCustomDesc. Can someone get me started on the MySQL? I am not sure where to start. My pages are using PHP.

**Database**

```
Students
1.) StID
2.) StNameFirst
3.) StNameLast
4.) StTitlePref
5.) fkProID

Tasks
1.) TkID
2.) TkSide (the task by nature has a side?: Y or N) 
3.) TkTitleSci
4.) TkTitleCom
5.) TkDesc

TaskInstance
1.) TkInstID
2.) TkInstSide (which side is the task?: L, R or null)
3.) TkInstCustomTitleSci
4.) TkInstCustomTitleCom
5.) TkInstCustomDesc
6.) fkTkID
7.) fkStID
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? You should try something before we do.

Comment: Where's your code? what have you tried?